# Upload file in WordPress with custom file name

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, dropzone.js

I'm currently developing a plugin for my page. The goal is to upload a custom profile image from a user page. Now I want to store each image under a pre-defined name. Sadly I've no plan how I can set a custom name for a file during the file upload with the WordPress function `wp_upload_bits()`:

```
$filename =  $_FILES['file']['name'];

$uploaded_bits = wp_upload_bits(
    $filename,
    null,
    file_get_contents( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] )
);
```

Currently when I upload for example an image with the name `yolo.png`, the name stays `yolo.png`.

Now I want to define the new name this way:

```
$filename = 'profile-image-' . get_current_user_id();
```

But this can't work because the `$_FILES['file']['name']` is the temporarily saved file on my server and this is `yolo.png`. So do you have any idea how I can reach my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I'm not that smart. I need to pass the file type, otherwise the upload can't work...:

```
$filename = 'profile-image-' . get_current_user_id() . '.' . substr( strrchr( $_FILES['file']['name'], '.' ), 1 );
```

With this part of code I just get the file extension:

```
'.' . substr( strrchr( $_FILES['file']['name'], '.' ), 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the file extension also by splitting the string

```
$arr = explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name']);
$ext = end($arr);
```

you then concatenate the file extension with the name you want.

you could also try to the function

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'path/to/folder/'.$filename);
```